# Add a link to the catalog.topnav in magento via a layout update

Tags: magento

Is it possible to add a link to the the catalog navigation in magento through a layout update - much the same way as you can use the addLink method for the top links and footer links etc.

Answer (score 2):

The layout entry for `catalog.topnav` is:

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
```

This means we're using the block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` (probably) and we're using the template file `catalog/navigation/top.phtml`.

In the template file we see that the rendering of the menu is perform through the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml()` method.

If we take a look at the implementation of that method in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` we see that it's populated by looping through the store's active categories.

So, out of the box, no you can't add to that file through layout updates.

---

As you say, there is already a block class that supports adding links through the XML called `page/template_links`.  My recommendation, would be to modify the XML to something like:

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="catalog.topnav.links" as="additional_links">
        <action method="addLink">
                <label>Our Boutiques</label>
                <url>boutiques</url>
                <title>Our Boutiques</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
                <position>1</position>
                <liParams/>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>
```

Then change the template file to something like:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional_links') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

The `page/template_links` block uses the `page/template/links.phtml` template as default which includes a wrapping `<ul>`.  If you wanted to include the links inside the `<ul>` that's already in the `catalog/navigation/top.phtml` template you could set a different template on the `page/template_link` block using the `template=""` attribute and create your own links template without the `<ul>`.

Comment: Just to supplement your comment, there's a bit of a guide here about how you can change the template and extend the `addLink` functionality. See http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/nested-xml-menus-using-addlink-in-magento/